# Firebase Analytics, unable to view the values that are passed in the event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am implementing Firebase Analytics in my app.

Everything works fine, I am getting the logged events in my Firebase console, but I am having trouble with the bundle data (Params) that are passed during the logging of event.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, "event Value");
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalyticsConstants.ON_VIEW_EVENT, bundle);
```

I want to differentiate based on the VALUE param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VALUE parameter is meant to be numeric.  See the documentation on it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#constant-summary).

Of course, you can log any custom parameter you want with your event, but parameter reporting is only currently offered on a subset of [suggested events](https://support.google.com/firebase/topic/6317484?hl=en&ref_topic=6386699).  Alternatively, you can query your raw events, parameters and user properties if you link your app to BigQuery.

Comment: params.putString("label", label); where does custom event goes ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue:

```html
 //pass this code in any click event or anywhere.
 
 FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("Category",category);
 bundle.putString("Screen",Screen);
 firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("MyCustomEvent",bundle);
```

Pass this command for track:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

not when your app is send event log you will see logs. Custom tag i used android studio's emulator. Geny motion set SDK path from  Genymotion: settings-> ADB.

Note: After 15-20 minutes open firebase console,  see right side and select today. you will find your custome event.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this snippet code**

```
findViewById(R.id.tvOrderTitle).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strClickLogs;

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("mobileno", logMobileno);
            params.putString("name", logName);
            params.putString("email", logEmail);

            strClickLogs = "Eventlogs_Generated";

            Log.e(TAG, strClickLogs);
            //Logs an app event.
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(strClickLogs, params);
        }
    });
```

You can see genrated logs in **verbose** in **Logcat** as below format:

V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=app,name=Eventlogs_Generated,params=Bundle[{mobileno=9876543210, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SupplierListActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7001228486350086694, name=Ashish Tikarye, email=ashisht@set.com}]